# Is the "Rails Way" for `update` fundamentally flawed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud

I'm intentionally asking this question in an inflammatory way because I'm concerned that I'm missing something.

The *Rails Way* for dealing with an update to a model is the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @current_user = load_user
    if @current_user.update_attributes params[:user]
      redirect_to success_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

This is all well and good except that you end up on an odd URL when the form submission is incorrect:

**Editing User**

You find yourself on the path:

```
users/:user_id/edit
```

**After submitting edits that don't validate**

i.e. you're going to need to fix the inputs in your form and resubmit:

```
users/:user_id
```

**After submitting edits that do validate**

```
success_path
```

***Why the hell should you be on a different URL just because the form has errors?***

---

**The problem...**

You're doing the same thing but you're now on a different URL. This is a bit odd.

In fact frankly it feels wrong. You're on a form which has not validated correctly and so has reloaded. You should still be on `/users/:user_id/edit`. If you'd done JS validation you would be.

Furthermore if you've got any "currently selected" logic going on in your navigation then you are in fact visually in the wrong place as the correct nav item is no longer highlighted - it looks like you're on the user profile page.

Comment: arguing specifics of a language is not a good fit

Comment: @KevinDTimm could you explain what you mean? It's a programming question about a framework and not a language question

Comment: You're arguing about the specifics of RoR - Why the hell should you be on a different URL just because the form has errors? - would be defined as a design decision about the language, not a discussion about how to do something within that language. The how has been defined, you don't agree with it - you said so yourself.

Comment: Ok, reasonable point. I've updated the question to be more specific about what I actually needed to know

Answer (score 6):

> Why the hell should you be on a different URL just because the form
>   has errors?

Because when you first went to:

```
users/:user_id/edit
```

...you were requesting a GET.

Then you POSTed to:

```
users/:user_id
```

So by sending the form post, you have requested a different resource route, and have a different URL by definition.

The framework doesn't care what happened in the background while your request was processing - all it knows is it was a POST (which by convention is not necessarily idempotent as a GET is)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand the mechanics of why the URL has changed however my question was actually different. I did not communicate that very well though and I've updated the question to reflect the real issue

Comment: The only question in your post is "why the hell...?". As I point out, the framework doesn't know errors were raised in the POST, and you've re-rendered the edit view. Regarding your "correct nav item comment"; maybe the process of how your navigation is highlighted shouldn't be hardcoded to what the URL says, but on some determination in the controller action that the URL routes to? ;-)

Comment: @Pavling I'm just wondering whom are you calling "the framework". Quote: "the framework doesn't know errors were raised". Who is raising the errors then?  On a more constructive note, looks like OP understands how it works, the question is why it is designed so? the `update` method could e.g. `else redirect_to_failure_path` which can be anything (back to `id/edit` or to `id/edit_please_correct_errors`). Of course that brings other problems but that's the point: which ones?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not the "Rails Way", it's "REST Way". Wikipedia: [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

If you follow the rules you get REST-compliant web-service for free. As I understand it the path "resource/id/edit" is specific to html documents. Web-service clients don't need form for editing.

So the guys were trying to be consistent. If you don't need web-service compatibility you can change the routes of course.

Comment: Fair point. I didn't really communicate my original question very well so have updated it to make it make more sense